# Fastest way for finding which combination of two list maximises a function in R

Tags: r

I have a data set `dat` and two lists `x` and `y`. I would like to calculate different combination of `x` and `y` with different value of `k`. I wrote the following code to find the value of function `fun` for these different combinations. but how can I get the value of `k` which maximize the function `fun` for these different combination? since in each iteration I have different lists of `x` and `y` and at the end I want to find the `k` which maximise the function `fun`.

```
    dat = c(9, 2, 7)
    k = seq(0, 1, length = 10)
    x =list(a = 1, b = 8, c = 4)
    y = list(a = .5, b = 5, c = 5)
    matrix = cbind(unlist(x), unlist(y)) %*% rbind(1-k, k)
    z = apply(matrix, 2, as.list)
    fun = function(dat, vec) sum(vec$a * dat - vec$b * dat + vec$c * dat)
    res = rep(0, length(k))
    for (i in 1:(length(k))){
        v = split(unlist(z[[i]]), sub("\\d+$", "", names(z[[i]])))
        res[i] = fun(dat, v)
    }

   > res
   [1] -54 -47 -40 -33 -26 -19 -12  -5   2   9
```

In this example, k = 10 , but how can I find for every different lists without loop?

Comment: You can probably use `mapply` although I am not sure how in this case - this can probably simplified a lot if it was more clear what you are trying to do!

Comment: I want to create all combination of (1-k)x +ky, and then calculate the function fun for each combination. Then find which k maximise the function "fun".

Answer (score 0):

I still can't make heads or tails of what you are trying to do, but your code seems to boil down to this:

```
colSums(matrix(rep(dat,nrow(matrix)),ncol=nrow(matrix)) %*% (matrix*c(1,-1,1)))
```

That will work for any size of `k`. It also does not require any of your `names`.

Some advice: Don't use `list` when a simple vector will do. You seem to understand how the `%*%` multiply works, you just need to get your matrices into the right form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How can I get which k get the maximum value of function fun ?